# Fulcrum Racing 5 LG freehub replacement - drag

Tags: maintenance, freehub

I just replaced a Fulcrum racing 5 LG free hub.  Once it was all together, it seems a bit tight.  With the bike on the stand, when I spin the pedals, and release, the pedals continue to rotate. So the free hub is not spinning as freely as I would expect.

I did not disassemble the entire axle and hub; I just removed the worn free hub from the drive side, and replaced it with a new free hub.  So, no changes, other than the free hub itself.

Will it loosen up? Is this related to the pre-load on the non-drive side of the axle?  Anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a couple of email exchanges with Campagnolo technical services of North America, I've confirmed that I correctly installed the new free hub (but you should do this carefully, as the pawls and/or spring can be damaged with too much pressure or twisting).  The technician confirmed that the new bearings could be a bit stiff as they "break in", but that things should loosen up appropriately.

So, I will put some miles on and confirm this as the answer once things loosen up.

Edit:  After about 100 miles (160 K) the bearings have loosened a bit and the wheel is spinning without dragging along the crank.  So, I believe that in this case, the new fulcrum freehub body did indeed need a break-in period.

Also:  as long as your wheel was stable on its axle before replacing the freehub body...don't mess with the pre-load mechanism.